# Excel 2007 VBA - Error: "Object variable or With Block variable not set" when using OLEDB connection to another Excel File

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

So my problem is that between 2 different computers my connection to the string no longer can open a connection.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sFilePath As String

sFileName = "DataSource.xls"
sFilePath = "C:\test\testingData\"

Dim sConn As String
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & sFilePath & sFileName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

Dim errorObject As ADODB.Error
Set errorObject = CreateObject("ADODB.Error")

On Error GoTo ErrorDisplay:

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open sConn

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset '* Record Set
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open sSql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly

Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

---

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE [Status] = 2 AND [DocNo] LIKE '%-A%'
```

---

When I run this section of code on one computer it runs perfectly as I built it. When I try it on a similar computer it keeps giveing an error **"Object variable or With Block variable not set"**. I have found out that the problem is with the ***conn.Open sConn*** but not sure what is causing it.

I have been searching about looking for a solution but as of yet I have not found anything that worked.

Additional Info: 
Both computers:
Windows 7 x64
Excel 2007 x32

Any thoughts as to why this would not work?

**--Update:**
I just finished trying the excel file with the macro out on a 3rd windows 7 computer and that one works fine.

**--Update:**
I have just tried running the program from

```
sFilePath = "C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\"
```

and

```
sFilePath = "C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\Test\"
```

The thing I would really like to know is that it's working from the ***"C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Desktop\Test\"*** but none of the others???

Comment: You sure the path is correct on the second computer??

Comment: Yes, I have double checked the path a few times. And it is indeed correct on both

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Primary Interop Assemblies are installed on both computers?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what that is. How would I check to see if it is installed?

Comment: It is a small program very easy to download and to install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346 it is intended for coupling .NET programs with MS Office but the connection string you are using is equivalent to the one used by .NET programs, so I guess that it is testing-worthy.

Comment: It's definately a strange problem since the 3 machines are just Ghosts of a master copy

Comment: Strange things tend to happen with MS Macros. Installing the Primary Interop Assemblies is a really quick process (less than 1 min. for downloading and installing) and might be useful anyway (you need that to perform any MS Office 2007 coupling with a .NET application), that's why my suggestion: it is a harmless and quick check.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code.

```
' Add reference to Adodb library
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

    Public Function CreateConnection() As Boolean
        On Error GoTo ErrorRet

        Dim X As Integer
        Dim sConn As String
        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim sFilePath As String

        X = 0
    Reconn:
        X = X + 1

        sFileName = "DataSource.xls"
        sFilePath = "C:\test\testingData\"

        sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sFilePath & sFileName & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open sConn

        CreateConnection = True
        Exit Function

    ErrorRet:
        If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
            GoTo Reconn
        Else
            If X > 5 Then
                CreateConnection = False
            Else
                GoTo Reconn
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Sub test()

        Dim sSql As String
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

        If CreateConnection Then
            sSql = "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$]"
            rst.Open sSql, conn
            Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

        End If

    End Sub
```